# How to interface with SaxParser code after RESTClient returned XML data?

Tags: android, sax

I need to parse the XML data returned from accessing a REST-based service to display only one single tag.  For example, parse the XML data shown below to display firstname tag and value John only.

```
<company>
 <staff>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Doe</lastname>

</staff>

</company>
```

I am struggling to figure out how to interface with the SAX parsing code once XML data is returned by RESTClient.  I tried different approaches after learning from different example codes but still cannot figure it out partly because they do not have the same exact purpose.  So please kindly teach me how to call/pass the data to the parsing code and what to return from the parsing code, whether the parsing code should be in a separate class, etc.  I am basically clueless without some guidance.  Relevant RESTClient code is presented below.  Thanks!

```
public class RESTClient {

public static String callRESTService(String url) {

    String result = null;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // Prepare a request object
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

    // Execute the request
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        // Get hold of the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
        // to worry about connection release

        if (entity != null) {

            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                            SAXParser sp;

            try (

                sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();


                DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
                xr.setContentHandler(handler);

                InputSource is = new InputSource(instream);
                xr.parse(is);

                //what should/can be returned here from the parsing code:
                //String, InputSource, InputStream?.  Convert data type?


            }


            catch (SAXException e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (ParserConfigurationException e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result; 
  }
)
```

Comment: you have to implement your own `DefaultHandler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://as400samplecode.blogspot.com/2011/11/android-parse-xml-file-example-using.html

You have to extend DefaultHandler and make your own XML handler where you will parse your xml.
You can see the example of extending Defaulthandler in above link.

Answer (score 1):

I insist that you should keep your parser code in separate file . Since RestClient is only responsible for sending and receiving  of data from remote location . This is would also provide u lose coupling between the two components . 

**what to return from the parsing code** Output of processor depends on your needs. (Personally i am returning List of HashMap)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you return a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) here.